# Confused with for range and break

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understand how *for* *range* works, but the problem comes when *break* is included.

First code:

From my understanding, if I have incremented *2* starting at *5*, then the break is at *9*, I will add every value until *9* - which is 5 + 7 + 9. Equaling to 21

```
mysum = 0  
for i in range(5,11,2):
   mysum += i
   if mysum == 7:
      break
print(mysum)
21
```

Second code:

```
mysum = 0
for i in range (5,20,2):
    mysum += i
    if mysum == 15:
       break    
print(mysum)
96
(second code)
```

But, if I have incremented *2* starting at *5*, then the break at *15*,
I will then add 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + 15. Which is 60.
But the shell gives 96 instead.

It looks like I didn't understand what the professor was trying to say.
I have repeated the same chapter but there was only one example. I've also tried google and youtube, but they don't seem to tackle this thing specifically(it's very overwhelming).

Comment: `if i == 15:` would give you 60. As `mysum` is adding `i` and not `2`, it is never equal to 15 so it runs through the full loop. Try printing to help yourself debug. Add this line after you increment `i`: `print(f"i: {i},\tmysum: {mysum}")`

Comment: When you reach a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful answers and accept the best (even if you have to write it yourself).  This allows Stack Overflow to archive your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are setting the break when `mysum == 15` will not break the loop because in the first loop:

```
mysum = 0
mysum = 0 + 5 = 5
mysum = 5 + 7 = 12
mysum = 12 + 9 = 21
...
mysum = 77 + 19 = 96
```

This goes on because `mysum` will never be equal to 15, hence the loop won't break, therefore it will iterate over all your numbers in the loop (5+7+9+11+13+15+17+19) which is equal to 96.
If you want to be `break` the loop at an specific number that will be added to `mysum` then you should change the `if` part to:

```
if i == 15:
   break
```

That will break the loop when the number being added is 15 and prevent further summation.

Comment: Wow, I finally understand it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're testing `mysum`, the cumulative sum of `i`, the loop index.  `mysum` is *never* equal to your test value (7 or 15), so you *never* execute a `break` statement.  Your loop completes normally, adding the entire arithmetic sequence.  Put a `print` statement in each loop to check those values:

```
mysum = 0
for i in range (5,20,2):
    mysum += i
    print(i, mysum, "\tLOOP ITERATION")
    if mysum == 15:
       print("Sum is 15; BAIL OUT!!")
       break    

print("FINAL:", mysum)
```

Output:

```
5 5     LOOP ITERATION
7 12    LOOP ITERATION
9 21    LOOP ITERATION
11 32   LOOP ITERATION
13 45   LOOP ITERATION
15 60   LOOP ITERATION
17 77   LOOP ITERATION
19 96   LOOP ITERATION
FINAL: 96
```

However, if you test the loop index, as your text implies:

```
mysum = 0
for i in range (5,20,2):
    mysum += i
    print(i, mysum, "\tLOOP ITERATION")
    if i == 15:
       print("Index is 15; BAIL OUT!!")
       break    

print("FINAL:", mysum)
```

Output:

```
5 5     LOOP ITERATION
7 12    LOOP ITERATION
9 21    LOOP ITERATION
11 32   LOOP ITERATION
13 45   LOOP ITERATION
15 60   LOOP ITERATION
Index is 15; BAIL OUT!!
FINAL: 60
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped me a lot!